# React, HTML and JavaScript: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using React and I am getting the following error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`. I did see some questions related to this error but I did not find any that helped me.

```
//React
class Pagination extends Component {

  pagincationScript = (totalPages, page) =>{
    const ulTag = document.querySelector("ul");

    let liTag = '';
    if(page > 1){
      liTag = `<li className="Btn Previous"><span><i>&#8592;</i>Previous</span></li>`
    }

ulTag.innerHTML = liTag;

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="Pagination">
        <ul>

        {this.pagincationScript(10, 5)}

        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: In general, if you're using `document.querySelector` you're not using React the right way.  Can you explain more about what you're trying to do and what your markup looks like?

Comment: Adding html manually like this in react is not the right way

Comment: Its just a <ul> tag as shown in the question within render(). I hope I answered your question

Comment: @jmargolisvt so basically for my school project I am building a basic pagination component that displays 20 rows of data per page. I am grabbing the tags using document.querySelector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283719/how-to-loop-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing React you should always be writing JSX, like in the `render` function you wrote. To render the `<li>` separately you can do something like the following:

```js
function Li() {
  return (
    <li className="Btn Previous"><span><i>&#8592;</i>Previous</span></li>
  )
}

export default function Pagination() {
  // Loop as many times as needed
  const lis = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    lis.push(<Li key={i} />);
  }

  return (
    <div className="Pagination">
      <ul>
        {lis}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did that and it works perfectly fine but I want to loop a certain amount of time to display the <li> tags. How can I use the for loop with the approach you mentioned above?

Comment: I added an example of looping 10 times, creating 10 <Li> elements.

Comment: Thank you so much! Dont know why people are so quick to give a down vote. I am still learning. But thank you so much. Your post helped and may you continue to help others like you helped me.